# Immutable.js Map: Find key from value

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an ImmutableJS map created like this:

```
const seatMap = Immutable.fromJS({
  seatOne: 'Martin',
  seatTwo: 'Emelie',
  seatThree: 'Erik'
});
```

I want to find out which seat a specific person is using. It can be assumed that the values will be unique.

I have come up with one solution so far:

```
const getSeatFromPerson = (seatMap, person) => {
  const [ ...keys ] = seatMap.keys();

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ {
    if (seatMap.get(keys[i]) === person) {
      return keys[i];
    }
  }

  return null;
};

console.log(getSeatFromPerson(seatMap, 'Martin')); // Should be "seatOne"
console.log(getSeatFromPerson(seatMap, 'Erik')); // Should be "seatThree"
console.log(getSeatFromPerson(seatMap, 'Christopher')); // Should be null
```

But this solution feels very "clunky" and not very neat or fast. Is there a built in method for this or a better way to do it?

Comment: As you would do in a database, your "indexes" should be based on the ways in which you perform lookups. If you want to look up by name, there should be a separate reverse Map.

Comment: I also sometimes need to find out who is sitting at a specific set (basically `seatmap.get('seatOne')`). Do you mean that I should create a different map with the same content, just the keys and values flipped around? The final number of seats might be up towards a hundred, and who sits on the seat is not static, people can switch seats.

Comment: The maps themselves only need to duplicate the property names and values, again just as with indexes in a database. The map values can also be links to objects kept in yet another collection. (I mean, you did ask for "a better way to do it".)

Comment: That's true, I did. I just didn't understand what you meant :)

Comment: Depending on how often you want to look up in reverse and how often this map is updated, you should keep track of 2 maps. Update both the maps in pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one line function that uses [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) :

```
const getSeatFromPerson = (seatMap, person) => [...seatMap.keys()].find(seat => seatMap.get(seat) === person) || null;
```